# Distinguishing stereoisomers using reagents

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Given the following possible reagents:

- acetone,
- $\ce{MnO2}$,
- ozone, or
- aluminium propoxide,

which one would distinguish between the cis and trans isomers of cyclopentan-1,2-diol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reagent listed that will distinguish between cis and trans diols is acetone. In the presence of catalytic acid it will form an acetal with the cis diol. This cannot occur with the trans diol as the two OH groups are too far apart. Try drawing the cis and trans diol in 3D.